Copy files from two level parents directory, Gulp?
I'm using gulp 5.0.0
It's my task:
gulp.task("theme", async () => {
  const destBasePath = "src/assets/vendors/theme/";
  gulp.src(["../../docs/theme/theme.js"])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat("theme.min.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destBasePath));
});

File ../../docs/theme/theme.js is exists, but I get the following error:
[07:49:43] Using gulpfile D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\gulpfile.js
[07:49:43] Starting 'default'...
[07:49:43] Starting 'theme-rtl'...
[07:49:43] Finished 'theme-rtl' after 8.07 ms
[07:49:43] Finished 'default' after 10 ms
node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

<ref *2> Error: File not found with singular glob: D:/Sources/Karnama/docs/theme/theme.js (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
    at D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:305:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EventEmitter.onEnd (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:302:11)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:551:15)
    at queue.drain (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:36:8)
    at Task.release (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\fastq\queue.js:157:12)
    at worked (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\fastq\queue.js:201:10)
    at D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:82:9
Emitted 'error' event on Domain instance at:
    at Transform.emit (node:domain:539:12)
    at ReadableState.afterDestroy (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\streamx\index.js:493:19)
    at Transform._destroy (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\streamx\index.js:629:5)
    at ReadableState.updateNonPrimary (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\streamx\index.js:386:16)
    at ReadableState.update (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\streamx\index.js:367:71)
    at ReadableState.updateReadNT (D:\Sources\Karnama\Apps\Karnama-Angular\node_modules\streamx\index.js:536:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
  domainEmitter: <ref *1> Transform {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      newListener: [Function: newListener],
      pipe: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onPipe] }
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _duplexState: 459316,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      stream: [Circular *1],
      queue: FastFIFO {
        hwm: 16,
        head: FixedFIFO {
          buffer: [ <16 empty items> ],
          mask: 15,
          top: 0,
          btm: 0,
          next: null
        },
        tail: FixedFIFO {
          buffer: [ <16 empty items> ],
          mask: 15,
          top: 0,
          btm: 0,
          next: null
        },
        length: 0
      },
      highWaterMark: 0,
      buffered: 0,
      readAhead: true,
      error: [Circular *2],
      pipeline: Pipeline {
        from: [Circular *1],
        to: DestroyableTransform {
          _readableState: ReadableState {
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 16,
            buffer: [BufferList],
            length: 0,
            pipes: [DestroyableTransform],
            pipesCount: 1,
            flowing: true,
            ended: false,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: true,
            sync: false,
            needReadable: true,
            emittedReadable: false,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            destroyed: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrain: 0,
            readingMore: false,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null
          },
          readable: true,
          _events: [Object: null prototype] {
            end: [Array],
            prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
            error: [Function: bound done],
            close: [Function: bound done],
            finish: [Function: bound finished],
            drain: [Function: bound afterDrain],
            data: [Function: ondata]
          },
          _eventsCount: 7,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: WritableState {
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 16,
            finalCalled: false,
            needDrain: false,
            ending: false,
            ended: false,
            finished: false,
            destroyed: false,
            decodeStrings: true,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            length: 0,
            writing: false,
            corked: 0,
            sync: true,
            bufferProcessing: false,
            onwrite: [Function (anonymous)],
            writecb: null,
            writelen: 0,
            bufferedRequest: null,
            lastBufferedRequest: null,
            pendingcb: 0,
            prefinished: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            bufferedRequestCount: 0,
            corkedRequestsFree: [CorkedRequest]
          },
          writable: true,
          allowHalfOpen: true,
          _transformState: {
            afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
            needTransform: true,
            transforming: false,
            writecb: null,
            writechunk: null,
            writeencoding: null
          },
          _destroyed: false,
          _transform: [Function (anonymous)],
          [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        afterPipe: null,
        error: null,
        pipeToFinished: false
      },
      byteLength: [Function: defaultByteLength],
      map: null,
      pipeTo: DestroyableTransform {
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: true,
          highWaterMark: 16,
          buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
          length: 0,
          pipes: DestroyableTransform {
            _readableState: [ReadableState],
            readable: true,
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 8,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            _writableState: [WritableState],
            writable: true,
            allowHalfOpen: true,
            _transformState: [Object],
            _destroyed: false,
            _transform: [Function: bufferContents],
            _flush: [Function: endStream],
            [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          pipesCount: 1,
          flowing: true,
          ended: false,
          endEmitted: false,
          reading: true,
          sync: false,
          needReadable: true,
          emittedReadable: false,
          readableListening: false,
          resumeScheduled: false,
          destroyed: false,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          awaitDrain: 0,
          readingMore: false,
          decoder: null,
          encoding: null
        },
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          end: [ [Function], [Function] ],
          prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
          error: [Function: bound done],
          close: [Function: bound done],
          finish: [Function: bound finished],
          drain: [Function: bound afterDrain],
          data: [Function: ondata]
        },
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: WritableState {
          objectMode: true,
          highWaterMark: 16,
          finalCalled: false,
          needDrain: false,
          ending: false,
          ended: false,
          finished: false,
          destroyed: false,
          decodeStrings: true,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          length: 0,
          writing: false,
          corked: 0,
          sync: true,
          bufferProcessing: false,
          onwrite: [Function (anonymous)],
          writecb: null,
          writelen: 0,
          bufferedRequest: null,
          lastBufferedRequest: null,
          pendingcb: 0,
          prefinished: false,
          errorEmitted: false,
          bufferedRequestCount: 0,
          corkedRequestsFree: CorkedRequest {
            next: null,
            entry: null,
            finish: [Function (anonymous)]
          }
        },
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState: {
          afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
          needTransform: true,
          transforming: false,
          writecb: null,
          writechunk: null,
          writeencoding: null
        },
        _destroyed: false,
        _transform: [Function (anonymous)],
        [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
      },
      afterRead: [Function: bound afterRead],
      afterUpdateNextTick: [Function: bound updateReadNT]
    },
    _writableState: WritableState {
      stream: [Circular *1],
      queue: FastFIFO {
        hwm: 16,
        head: FixedFIFO {
          buffer: [ <16 empty items> ],
          mask: 15,
          top: 0,
          btm: 0,
          next: null
        },
        tail: FixedFIFO {
          buffer: [ <16 empty items> ],
          mask: 15,
          top: 0,
          btm: 0,
          next: null
        },
        length: 0
      },
      highWaterMark: 0,
      buffered: 0,
      error: [Circular *2],
      pipeline: null,
      drains: null,
      byteLength: [Function: defaultByteLength],
      map: null,
      afterWrite: [Function: bound afterWrite],
      afterUpdateNextTick: [Function: bound updateWriteNT]
    },
    _predestroy: [Function: predestroy],
    _transformState: TransformState {
      data: null,
      afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
      afterFinal: [Function: bound afterFinal]
    },
    _flush: [Function: flush],
    _read: [Function (anonymous)],
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  domainThrown: false
}

Node.js v20.11.0

I change gulp.src(["../../docs/theme/theme.js"]) to gulp.src(["../../docs/theme/theme.js"], {base: "./"}) but nothing changed.
It will be OK if the file was in the same directory or sub directories. I tested

What folder are the files you want stored?  It looked in D:/Sources/Karnama/docs/theme/theme.js - is that the right place?

D:/Sources/Karnama/docs/theme/theme.js is source,  and yep, the file exist
